# Change CSS Grid vertical gap between rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How do I change the vertical gap in between each grid row?

[image]

I have tried with `grid-gap`, but that only changes the horizontal gap—not vertical. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header header header' 'menu content content content content' 'menu content content content content' 'footer footer footer footer footer';
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  margin: 10px;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  margin: 10px;
}

.menu-item {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid white 1px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.madeby {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.content {
  list-style: none;
  grid-area: content;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

.top {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cell {
  border: solid white 1px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="top">header</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
    <li class="menu-item">menu</li>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="dato">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="nøkkelvaner">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="oppsumering">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="oppgaver">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="andre">
    <input class="cell" type="text" value="dato">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="madeby">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows):

**grid-auto-rows**

> The `grid-auto-rows` `CSS` property specifies the size of an
>   implicitly-created grid row track.
>
> If a grid item is positioned into a row that is not explicitly sized
>   by `grid-template-rows`, implicit grid tracks are created to hold it.
>   This can happen either by explicitly positioning into a row that is
>   out of range, or by the auto-placement algorithm creating additional
>   rows.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#max-content):

**min-content**

> `min-content` is a keyword representing the largest minimal content contribution of the grid items occupying the grid track.

In `.content`,

Replace this:

```css
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

With this:

```css
grid-auto-rows: min-content;
```

**Result:**

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efun4Lv5/1/)

Answer (score 15):

You can use `grid-gap` property to solve this, It's a shorthand property for `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap`. The first value is horizontal gap (row gap), second value is vertical gap (column gap)

`grid-gap: 10px 20px;`

You can also use the following properties to set gap between the grids:

`grid-row-gap: 10px;`

`grid-column-gap: 20px;`

**According to the Mozilla Docs:**

> This property is specified as a value for <'row-gap'> followed optionally by >value for <'column-gap'>. If <'column-gap'> is omitted, it’s set to the same >value as <'row-gap'>.

So, in your code you only sets the grid-gap for row, you should also add the second value for column (vertical)

Comment: Hello, I've tried "grid-gap" but it still won't work for me. works on horizontal but not on vertical for some reason.

Comment: Updated my answer, you should also set the second value in the `grid-gap` property. it should be `grid-gap: 5px 10px`

Answer (score 1):

The `grid-gap` property defines the size of the gap between the rows and columns in a grid layout, and is a shorthand property for the following properties:

You can use also `grid-row-gap` or `grid-column-gap`

Comment: `grid-row-*` property is deprecated. use `row-gap` or `column-gap`